# Тибет: "на" или "в"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как в русском языке нормируется употребление предлогов применительно к горной системе "Тибет": "на Тибет, на Тибет и т. д." или "в Тибете, в Тибет и т. д."?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что логичнее звучит все-таки "в Тибете", тем более, что Тибет - это не только горная система, но и историческая область Китая, почти что отдельное государство.

Answer (score 1):

В Тибет - в горы, в страну (ср. в Гималаи)
На Тибет - в историко-георгафическую область (ср. на Кавказ)

Первый вариант сейчас активно вытесняет второй.

Comment: Непонятно, первый вытесняет, а второй вытесняется, — это вы имели в виду?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой. Да. Имел в виду, что второй вытесняется первым. А суть подтвердить уже не могу, давно писано. Но, вроде, ничего не изменилось. Касательно же Вашего непонимания - это интересно.  Если "Снег накрыл город"  или, там, "Петренко спросил Иваненко" - у Вас сомнений не возникает?

Comment: Действительно, интересно!) В первом, конечно, не может быть наоборот по смыслу, а во втором нет полной уверенности, просто предполагаешь, что скорее Петренко спросил, чем его спросили. То же, что и у вас в ответе, — вроде так, но нету полной уверенности.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, я так понял, что Вы впервые столкнцлись с этой известной проблемой русской грамматики. На самом деле это даже у Розенталя описано.  Чтобы не морочить голову: в тех случаях, когда субъект и объект не различимы по форме (винительный=именительному) *субъект (он же - действующее, агенс) почти всегда идет первым, объект (он же - получатель, пациенс) - вторым*. Иное приходится оговаривать. Так что Петренко (кто) спросил/убил/любил Иваненко (кого). Ваши предположения правильны, но это больше чем предположения, это постулатив стилистки.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать!!)

Answer (score 0):

Верно и то, и другое.